# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered on line 234

Tags: php

With php 7.2 I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in on line 234

Here is what line 234 looks like:

```
$options['cpuLimit'] + 1, # hard limit
```

Togehter with the rest of the code:

```
if ( php_uname( 's' ) == 'Linux' ) {
    // Limit memory and CPU
    $cmd = wfEscapeShellArg(
        'exec', # proc_open() passes $cmd to 'sh -c' on Linux, so add an 'exec' to bypass it
        '/bin/sh',
        __DIR__ . '/lua_ulimit.sh',
        $options['cpuLimit'], # soft limit (SIGXCPU)
        $options['cpuLimit'] + 1, # hard limit
        intval( $options['memoryLimit'] / 1024 ),
        $cmd );
}
```

Anyone know how to fix the error?

Comment: Are you sure that `$options['cpuLimit']` is actually a number ?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use intval() to get an integer from the value:**

```
intval($options['cpuLimit']) + 1;
```

Before using intval you might want to check if that value is a number in the first place. You can do that with is_numeric();

```
if (is_numeric($options['cpuLimit']) == true) {
    intval($options['cpuLimit']) + 1;
}
```

Source: [PHP-intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) [PHP-is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Comment: Actually the cast will fight symptoms, not the cause. If the options are provided by other code, it's ok if there is an error for non-numerical options. If you follow _design by contract_, that is (: